# Set State doesn't change the value just if hot reload the page

Tags: flutter

I have the following situation

```
Column(
  children: [
    Tabs(),
    getPage(),
], 
),
```

the getPage method

```
   Widget getPage() {
      if (tab1IsSelected == true) {
        return Container(
          child: Center(
            child: Text('Tab1'),
          ),
        );
      }
      if (tab1IsSelected == false) {
        return Container(
          child: Center(
            child: Text('Tab2'),
          ),
        );
      }
    }
```

and globally I have declared a variable

```
bool tab1IsSelected = true;
```

In the Tabs Class (statefull):

```
class Tabs extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _TabsState createState() => _TabsState();
}

class _TabsState extends State<Tabs> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Row(
      children: [
        Expanded(
          child: GestureDetector(
            onTap: () {
              setState(() {
                tab1IsSelected = true;
              });
            },
            child: Container(
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: tab1IsSelected ? primary : second,
              ),
              child: Padding(
                padding:
                    EdgeInsets.only(top: 1.5 * SizeConfig.heightMultiplier),
                child: Center(
                  child: Text(
                    'New Hunt',
                    style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.bodyText1,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
        Expanded(
          child: GestureDetector(
            onTap: () {
              setState(() {
                tab1IsSelected = false;
              });
            },
            child: Container(
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: tab1IsSelected ? second : primary,
              ),
              child: Padding(
                padding:
                    EdgeInsets.only(top: 1.5 * SizeConfig.heightMultiplier),
                child: Center(
                  child: Text(
                    'My Hunts',
                    style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.bodyText2,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

I change the value of that bool, but only if I hot reload the page the content is changing. Why?
Can you guide me please?

I've tried to use  ? : in that Column but the same result and if I declare that variable in the Main Class where the Column is, I can't access it in the Tabs class, so that's why I declared it globally, maybe that's the cause I have to hot reload, but how can I implement that to do what I want. Thank you in advance

Comment: You are calling `setState` within the `Tabs` widget, so that's the widget that will refresh, not the parent widget or any other widgets not directly descendent of it. Hot reload triggers a refresh of the entire widget tree.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

setState is inside `_TabsState` so it will only affect/rebuilt that particular widget, not `getPage()`, you could try using `ValueChanged<bool>` to retrieve the new value and then using setState in the widget that wraps the `getPage()`

```
class Tabs extends StatefulWidget {
  final ValueChanged<bool> onChanged;

  Tabs({this.onChanged});


  @override
  _TabsState createState() => _TabsState();
}

class _TabsState extends State<Tabs> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Row(
      children: [
        Expanded(
          child: GestureDetector(
            onTap: () => widget.onChanged(true), //pass the value to the onChanged
            child: Container(
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: tab1IsSelected ? primary : second,
              ),
              child: Padding(
                padding:
                    EdgeInsets.only(top: 1.5 * SizeConfig.heightMultiplier),
                child: Center(
                  child: Text(
                    'New Hunt',
                    style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.bodyText1,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
        Expanded(
          child: GestureDetector(
            onTap: () => widget.onChanged(false), //pass the value to the onChanged
            child: Container(
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: tab1IsSelected ? second : primary,
              ),
              child: Padding(
                padding:
                    EdgeInsets.only(top: 1.5 * SizeConfig.heightMultiplier),
                child: Center(
                  child: Text(
                    'My Hunts',
                    style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.bodyText2,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Now on the widget with the column (That should be a StatefulWidget for setState to work)

```
Column(
  children: [
    Tabs(
      onChanged: (bool value) => setState(() => tab1IsSelected = value);
    ),
    getPage(),
  ], 
),
```

everytime you change the value of `tab1IsSelected` it will update `getPage()`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to rebuild a widget when something in its state changes you need to call the setState() of the widget.
The variable is referenced to the State class and when you call setState() Flutter will rebuild the widget itself by calling the build() method of the State class.

If you want to have some variables outside the widgets I suggest you to use a state management approach listed here: https://flutter.dev/docs/development/data-and-backend/state-mgmt/options.

For example you could use Provider to store the active tab and reference the provider variable in both widgets.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to handle the setstate in the parent class holding the Tab Widget then pass a the function to tab class and execute it in the gesture detector.